# Date parsing/converting with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, date

I am working on a personal project where I need to get a date using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) convert it to UTC and send it to an API formated as one of the ISO8601 formats ("yyy-mm-dd").

I am using Angular in the front and Rails in the backend API. The problem is that as the application will use multiple locales, the date format sent from date-picker to the angular controller will vary, it can be "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy".

How would I be able to make the proper adjustments to send the date to the API independently of the frontend format?

Comment: does your controller know if the format is "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy".

Comment: I can make the controller be aware of the format, but I could not figure out how to create a Date object in javascript with the date string and format. If I could do this then the problem would be solved.

Comment: Why can't you use the [getUTCDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#getutcdate) method and handle that date accordingly?

Comment: As getUTCDate is a frontent component method, I would prefer to avoid using it, as it would create a dependency from the presentation layer at the controller layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the answer is simple:
Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

With moment you can easily parse Dates in diffrent formats:

```
moment("12-25-1995", "yyy-mm-dd");
moment("12/25/1995", "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

[Doc for parsing dates with moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: Just had to use capital letters in the format argument for it to work.
Thanks!